# Disable TV tuner at boot

Tags: boot, tv-tuner

I have a TV tuner card (Leadtek Winfast TV2000 Global). It isn't fully supported by Ubuntu (and Linux kernel). It isn't a problem, because my dad only use it in Windows. But I've got an error message every Ubuntu boot. Can I disable this device for Ubuntu?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include the module in:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

? You need to know it's name, maybe by studying the logs.

Comment: Simplest: `dmesg | less` another test: `lsmod | grep tv`